# Access constructor name and arguments

Tags: haskell, dynamic, equals

I'm going to override the equal class for Dynamic data type in this way:

```
instance Eq Dynamic where 
    x==y = dynamicEq x y
dynamicEq :: Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Bool
dynamicEq x y = ConstrName x == ConstrName y && sameSlots(slots x)(slots y)
    where 
    sameSlots [] [] = True
    sameSlots ((x::Eq a => a):xs)(y:ys) = x == fromDynamic y && sameSlots xs ys
```

can you name or declare any function that can return the values of *ConstrName* and *slots* for me? Maybe using Tycon or something similar?

Comment: I think creating an `Eq` instance for `Dynamic` is impossible. To compare two objects, if you know the types, you're done, and if not, you're in trouble - you can't convert the values back to the static world since you don't know what types to coerce to, and you can't make `(==)` `Dynamic` unless you give it a monomorphic type (and how else could you make a dynamic equality predicate?). (See [the API](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html).) Unless this is an experiment, there's likely a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can derive the Eq behavior of Dynamic from the static type?

Comment: I think there's a good reason why the authors of `Data.Dynamic` didn't provide such an instance, which is that you cannot write one :)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Every static type I declare has it's own Eq instance, and moreover they are typeable and can be cast to Dynamic. I want the final Dynamic type be able of comparison the way it's corresponding static type does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never fiddled with this stuff, but here may be two partial answers which could be enough for you. I'm afraid it's not a general solution nor a way to make `Dynamic` and instance of `Eq` (it would probably be one already if it was easy).

But in your last comment you stated that you only wanted to compare your own types. So, partial answer 1:

You can of course compare two `Dynamics` if you guess their type. For example:

```
eqInt :: Int -> Int -> Bool
eqInt = (==)

x = toDyn (3::Int)
y = toDyn (3::Int)
z = toDyn (4::Int)

compareDynamic :: (Typeable a, Eq a) => 
               (a -> a -> Bool) -> 
               Dynamic -> Dynamic -> Maybe Bool
compareDynamic eq x y = do
               let dEq = toDyn eq
               fn1 <- dynApply dEq x
               res <- dynApply fn1 y
               fromDynamic res
```

And now:

```
...> compareDynamic eqInt x y
Just True
...> compareDynamic eqInt x z
Just False
```

However, despite the misleading polymorphic type of `compareDynamic`, you can only pass in a monomorphic comparison function. See:

```
...> compareDynamic (==) x z
Nothing
```

I suppose that is because the type system has no way of knowing which instance of `(==)` it should actually use here. I kept `compareDynamic` polymorphic though so you don't have to create separate functions for each type.

Now, since you only want to compare your own types, you could just have a list of comparison functions which you try in order:

```
eqs = [eqMyTypeA, eqMyTypeB, eqMyTypeC]
comp dynA dynB = catMaybes $ map (\eq -> eq dynA dynB) eqs
```

And `[]` would denote two different types, `[Just False]` the same type with different values and `[Just True]` the same type and value.

In case you have a large number of types, you can also determine the constructor before doing any comparison, (this is partial answer 2) and select the right function depending on it. It the constructors are different, you wouldn't have to try compare at all:

```
constructor :: Dynamic -> TyCon
constructor = typeRepTyCon . dynTypeRep
```

And have a lookup table matching constructors to equality functions.

One closing remark: Think twice if you need this. Think thrice if you need `Dynamic` at all, most Haskell programs don't. Isn't it just Java thinking sneaking in?